# What are appropriate French valedictions/complimentary closes for a letter from a guy to a guy?

Tags: choix-de-mot, politesse, correspondance

Even more specific, what's the most intimate close (i.e. to your closest guy best friend - practically a brother who has literally saved your life a few times), that you can use finishing a letter en français, without it sounding weird?

Comment: What makes you think that gender is relevant here?

Comment: In general, there's a different level of social intimacy you would use between 2 guys than you would between 2 girls, at least in America anyways.  Culturally it's always different - say, in Japan, 2 ladies may hold hands because they're close friends, just like 2 guys might hold hands in Pakistan.  Elsewhere, it might mean something WAY different.

Comment: I mean, if your concern is that a valediction could be misunderstood as a declaration of romantic interest (which sounds pretty weird to me: if you are so close, it's hard to imagine such ambiguity) why would the gender of the person you are writing to make a difference? Shouldn't the situation be just as weird if it were a man writing to a woman?

Comment: If you're so close to somebody, I think anything would be appropriate. Actually the more formal they would get, the less appropriate it would be. I would find it strange if a friend of mine would end up with a "Cordialement" (common in formal emails). You may also even forget about a valediction: when writing to someone so close, in our days, the common rules don't really apply in my opinion.

Comment: Dans un cas comme celui-là, j'éviterais une formule classique et utiliserais une phrase personnalisée. Difficile d'être précis sans connaître la personne ou sa situation. Par exemple : *prends soi de toi*, *à tes amours*, *la force est avec toi*, etc.

Comment: @Beau319 You're right. J.-P. Colignon (1983, cf *infra*) indique : "Formules-types : | 1) Lettres à des proches (parents, amis intimes, amis – *avec parfois une nuance plus respectueuse à l'égard d'une femme*)."

Comment: J'adore "La Force est avec toi!" MDR :D  Parfait!

Answer (score 3):

Quelque chose de personnel serait peut-être effectivement préférable, comme

> Reçois, cher Ami, mon salut fraternel

ou bien

> À plus, frérot

Tout dépend du niveau de langue que vous employez entre vous. Pour quelque chose de plus précieux, *Ab imo pectore* (du fond du cœur) insiste au fond sur le fait que : *1o*, vous ne voulez pas employer *cordialement*, qui aujourd’hui n’a plus ce sens étymologique ; *2o*, vous voulez montrer que vous feignez de parler latin.

Une source à mon sens délicieuse, sur ces questions de savoir-vivre distingué (à tous les sens du terme), est le défunt site *Savoir-vivre ou mourir*, dont [des copies subsistent sur l'Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160407162909/http://francois.darbonneau.free.fr/index2.html).

**Ajout :**

Jean-Pierre Colignon (qui fut chef correcteur au *Monde*) dans *Savoir écrire, savoir téléphoner* (Duculot, 1983,  p. 30-31) donne une liste de formules-types concernant le courrier adressé à des proches :

> *À toi ; Bien à toi ; Amicalement ; Cordialement ; Bien amicalement ; Cordialement vôtre ; Avec toutes mon amitié ; Reçois, cher Jacques,
> mon amical souvenir ; Cordiales pensées ; Mon affectueux souvenir ;
> Bien affectueusement vôtre ; Croyez, cher ami, à mon souvenir le
> meilleur ; Je vous serre cordialement la main ; Recevez, chère
> Christine, l'expression de ma respectueuse amitié.*

Dans le même passage, l'auteur ordonne quelques terminaisons finales de formules de politesse ; pour information, voici les trois plus intimistes, par ordre croissant :

> ... toute notre amitié.
>
> ... mon amical souvenir.
>
> ... cordialement vôtre.

Il importe donc de bien noter que ce *cordialement*, aujourd'hui parfaitement uniforme, devrait en réalité induire une relation plus étroite que la simple amitié...

Comment: Vous êtes une véritable pléthore d'informations!  J'admire :D

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

Standard formulas, appropriate for a letter to a friend:

- Bien à toi (not only used for friends, but appropriate also for any person you know in person , eg colleagues, neighbours, etc. There is also a "vous" form "bien à vous", but I assume you will call your friend "tu" , as most people do)
- Amitiés
- Amicalement
- avec toute mon amitié

If you want to suggest you are looking forward to meet again soon:

- à bientôt
- à plus (very informal)
- à la prochaine (informal)

If you just want to give a short, informal every day greeting:

- salut
- tchao/ciao

In France and some other French-speaking countries, close friends (even male) often kiss when they say goodbye, so it is acceptable to use formulas that refer to kissing in writing too, if this is a habit you have with your friend:

- je t'embrasse
- bises (I feel this is rather feminine greeting, but in a letter from a man to man, that can denote a bantering tone - it is common, for male friends, to pretend to have a humorous "macho" attitude and call male friends with feminine nicknames, eg "ma poule", "ma biche", etc)

Comment: Hilarant!  C'est parfait, surtout ce dernier :)